# Cannot change sequence name on Hibernate 3.6.10 with annotations (Oracle 10g)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle10g, jpa-2.0

I have a class annotated like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MYENTITY")
@SequenceGenerator(name="CODE_GEN", sequenceName="SEQ_NAME")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="CODE_GEN")    
    @Column(name="CODE", nullable=false)
    private int code;
```

I'm using hibernate 3.6.10 and Oracle10gDialect. The database is Oracle 10g. A sequence was created:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SCHEMA_NAME.SEQ_NAME
  START WITH 0
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 0
  NOCYCLE
  NOCACHE
  NOORDER;
COMMIT;
```

When I try to persist a MyEntity class, I get:

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
19-jul-2012 13:31:24 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
19-jul-2012 13:31:24 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
GRAVE: ORA-02289: sequence not exist
```

Why is hibernate always trying to access hibernate_sequence if I'm declaring the sequence name with @SequenceGenerator (sequenceName="SEQ_NAME")? Is there something wrong in my annotations?

I have tried lots of combinations and Hibernate always ignores the sequence name and looks for "hibernate_sequence". BTW I'm using GenerationType.AUTO because this app must also runs vs SQLServer.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally was able to use my own sequences using hibernate's own annotation, as it seems that this version doesn't completely support the annotation @SequenceGenerator. So the code ended up  like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MYENTITY")
@GenericGenerator(name="CODE_GEN", strategy = "native", parameters = 
                  { @Parameter(name="sequence", value="SEQ_NAME")})
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="CODE_GEN")    
    @Column(name="CODE", nullable=false)
    private int code;
```

Replacing @SequenceGenerator with @GenericGenerator did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JPA spec, @SequenceGenerator can either annotate a class or a primary key field. I think it's worth a try to move it to the field and see, if that works.

Comment: I had it originally at the field, with no luck.